# Is sync.Map atomic? Mainly I mean Load, Store, LoadOrStore, Delete

Tags: go

As tile, I am referring to Go package [sync.Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map), can its functions be considered as atomic? Mainly the `Load`, `Store`, `LoadOrStore`, and `Delete` function.

I also build a simple example [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/q2zFtIT1G4j), is it guaranteed that only one goroutine can enter the code range **line 15 - 17**? As my test seems it can be guaranteed.

Please help to explain.

Comment: That depends on what your definition of "atomic" is. It is safe to call these methods concurrently and you will never get garbled data. Never. For the second question: Yes (When in doubt: read the code).

Comment: @Volker, thank u, but if i do the `d.a.Store(key, 233)` after line 16, like this: https://play.golang.org/p/ZRwWRuYRrFS, then is there a chance the line 14 result to false? that means is there a chance the line 16 Store call cause a gap there is no value for that key?

Comment: @lnshi, yes `LoadOrStore` works as documented, though the stored values in your example could be anywhere from `[0, 1000)`.

Answer (score 2):

The [godoc](https://godoc.org/sync#Map) page for the sync package says: "Map is like a Go `map[interface{}]interface{}` but is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines without additional locking or coordination."

This statement guarantees that there's no need for additional mutexes or synchronization across goroutines. I wouldn't call that claim "atomic" (which has a very precise meaning), but it does mean that you don't have to worry about multiple goroutines being able to enter a `LoadOrStore` block (with the same key) like in your example.

Comment: can u also help to address the concern i put in the main question's comment: if i do the `d.a.Store(key, 233)` after line 16, like this: play.golang.org/p/ZRwWRuYRrFS, then is there a chance the line 14 result to false? that means is there a chance the line 16 Store call cause a gap that there is no value for that key(same key)?